# background position more than 100% works different why?

Tags: background-position

I have a problem with background positioning.
I want background image moves out of it's container and i want to do it with background-position: 150% center for example.
Now the problem is in different resolutions, these % values have differences.
For example, in 1360px resolution, my background image moves out with value of 175% of horizontal.
But in 360px resolution, my background image moves out with value of 4500% of horizontal.
Do you have any solution for this problem?
thank you.

```css
.airplane{
    width: 100%;
    height: 126px;
    background-image: url("../img/book.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: 175% center;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
</div>
```

Comment: "I want background image moves out of it's container". why woud you do that can't you modify your html to have an structure which will contain the background image?

Comment: Probably you didn't understand, my book is about 200px and i want to move it from out of the page container into middle of page and then move it again to negative % value and make it disappear.